# Simple preg_replace for variable strings to values not working

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I am just trying to make it so that `{string}` will turn into the value of the `$string` variable.

For example, consider I have the following variables:

```
$car = 'Audi';
$speed = 'Fast';
$sentence = "The {car} goes {speed}";
```

I want this to output: `The Audi goes Fast`

Here is my code which is not working:

```
$setting['leads_low_subject'] = '{dealer_name} has {leads_left} leads left!';
$dealer_name = 'My Test Dealer';
$leads_left = 6;

$subject = preg_replace('/\{([a-z]+)\}/e', "$$1", $setting['leads_low_subject']);

echo $setting['leads_low_subject'].'<br />';
echo "$subject";
```

This is echoing:

```
{dealer_name} has {leads_left} leads left!
{dealer_name} has {leads_left} leads left!
```

When it should be echoing:

```
{dealer_name} has {leads_left} leads left!
My Test Dealer has 6 leads left!
```

Why is it not working properly?

Comment: `{dealer_name}` has an underscore, but you match `[a-z]+`, might try with `[a-z_]+` or `\w+` where `\w` is a shorthand to `[A-Za-z0-9_]`

Comment: str_replace would be a much better idea

Comment: i knew it was something rediculously simple. thank you jonny. dagon, im aware of the security flaws, but the $setting variable content is not publicly accessible and will never contain a malicious string.

Comment: @scarhand the `e` modifier is deprecated. Use `preg_replace_callback()` as a replacement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fastest way i see is to use strtr():

```
$trans = array( '{car}'   => 'Audi',
                '{speed}' => 'Fast');

$result = strtr($sentence, $trans);
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you are looking for a *poor man's* template engine. You could use `preg_replace_callback()`:

```
$tpl_vars = array(
    'car' => 'Ford',
    'speed' => 'fast'
);


$tpl = 'The {car} goes {speed}';

echo preg_replace_callback('/\{(.*?)\}/', function($match) use ($tpl_vars) {
    return $tpl_vars[$match[1]];
}, $tpl);
```